# Opencv Aruco board detection crashes on detectMarkers()

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I'm trying to calibrate my camera to use it for fiducial tracking with aruco and opencv. For that I'm using the sample file that comes with Aruco.

[The sample file I just copy pasted](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/aruco/samples/detect_board_charuco.cpp)

Now the program starts and the window showing the camera output opens but as soon as the program starts to detect something, it crashes. 
I think I narrowed it down to this piece of code but I have no idea how to solve the error and the debugger isn't really telling me anything useful either:

```
// detect markers
    aruco::detectMarkers(image, dictionary, markerCorners, markerIds, detectorParams,
                         rejectedMarkers);
```

The Error shows something like:
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE653D3D0 (opencv_core320d.dll) 
Access violation while reading at position 0x0000000000000008

(Sorry, the error is in german and I tried to translate it)

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Win 7 
I wasted hours on this and I'm really out of ideas

Comment: Have you recompiled OpenCV with contrib modules with vc11 compiler?

Comment: Yes, I'm using most recent contrib modules which I built with cmake

Comment: Then it's wierd... what does your debugger says? Where does it crash?